# PowerShell remnant character from registry pull

Tags: powershell

When pulling this install string from the registry, there is an invisible leading character.

I am unable to run the uninstall string or strip this character. Various iterations of split, replace, join, etc work against the string, but do nothing to change the errant behaviour. I have tried within PowerShell or the Windows console.

`Write-Output $uninst` shows the correct string:

```
MsiExec.exe  /x {1F4D7BAB-E816-43DF-B4B1-5A41A2DA13E8} /qn
```

When executing that string in PowerShell, the `msiexec` help bubble pops up. When executing that string at the Windows CMD shell, a white square character is at the beginning of the line.

```
# pull ESET uninstall string

$esetVer = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
           Get-ItemProperty |
           Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match "ESET Endpoint Antivirus" } |
           Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString

foreach ($ver in $esetVer) {
    if ($ver.UninstallString) {
        $uninst = $ver.UninstallString
        $uninst = $uninst.Replace('/I{',' /x {').Replace('}','} /qn')
        Invoke-Expression $uninst
        Write-Output $uninst
    }
}
```

Removing first char only removes the M.

[image: Bad character]

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please take a little time to at least read the minimum of necessary information about how to use this site. You might start with [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and at least read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'll try again. I pasted the script, but it turned into an image. Noobs, eh.

Comment: There is a distinct difference between the `"String".Replace()` method and the `-replace` operator of Powershell. One works with regular expresisons the other don't.  ;-)

Comment: If you would extract only the product code of the application you want to uninstall (the number between the curly braces including the curly braces) you could build the uninstall string by yourself.

Comment: I suspect that your bat is saved using  Unicode encoding (`UTF16` with `BOM`).   Open it in `notepad` and save back using `ANSI` encoding.

Comment: Thank you @Olaf you led me to $item.Split() to pull out the product ID. Now to figure out how to close this post with solution...

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ but automation was the goal here

Comment: For fixing non-working automation you first need to find out what exactly doesn't work. Please show the output of `Get-Content -Raw esetoutout.cmd | Format-Hex` and `$uninst | Format-Hex`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you are close however  `Get-Content -Raw` _understands_ BOM so you need to run `Get-Content esetoutout.cmd -Encoding Byte | Format-Hex`.

Comment: If _automation was the goal here_ then where the `esetoutout.txt` comes from? Please add to your [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ Ah, you're right. My mistake.

Comment: Hmmm ... why using cmd.exe anyway? You already use a CLI when you use Powershell. So you're running a CLI from another CLI !!! That's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In my question, I focus on some errant character before the msiexec.exe command line. That apparently was not the issue. The issue was the braces around the app ID ( {1F4D7BAB-E816-43DF-B4B1-5A41A2DA13E8} ). They required a backtick. So, simply including the backtick before the brace in my substitution line fixed the code.

Old: $uninst = $uninst.Replace('/I{',' /x {').Replace('}','} /qn')

New: $uninst = $uninst.Replace('/I{',' /x `{').Replace('}','`} /qn')

This modification worked on 2 Windows 7 Pro computers.